# "azure" not recognized in Azure powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-powershell

For the first time I'm trying out Azure Powershell.
I'm selected my subscription and am trying to run the following command:
azure site log tail websitename

However when I run the command I get the following error:

```
azure : The term 'azure' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example command is an [Azure cross-platform command line](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) command. The equivalent PowerShell command is:

```
Get-AzureWebsiteLog websitename -Tail
```

Comment: I see. However when entering the command you specified it doesn't recognize the -Tail parameter.

Comment: What version of the cmdlets do you have? That switch was available in at least 0.6.19. You can find out by running `(Get-Module Azure).Version`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the powershell tool for the azure from azure site. This is another utility which recognise all the cmdlts which is assosicated with azure. After that it's very easy to use powershell ise.